# MongoDB date index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, indexing, mongoose

I am using node.js and mongodb for my small application and I want to index my document by date object. For Example

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

myschema.index({created_at: -1});
```

But how I understand, each object will have nearly unique create_id field. Wouldit work well ? and would this method give me effect. If you can, please also send me any articles about mongodb date indexing.

Comment: Surely it will work well if you aim "_to index my document by date_". Do you have any other goals? any reasons to create the index? what effect you expect?

Comment: @AlexBlex I want to query millions of document by date in some range. I want to know would indexing method help to query faster ? How will work indexing if any document have unique field ?

Comment: Yes, if the index is used for a range query, it speed it up. Not sure what unique field is, but you can read more about how indexes work [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/).